Unknown numpy data type: object for using nx.from_numpy_array
mat_L1 = mat_L1_df.to_numpy()[1:,1:]
L1_G = nx.from_numpy_array(mat_L1, parallel_edges=False, create_using=nx.DiGraph)  

I want to make a graph.
However, nx.from_numpy_array didn't recognize numpy array data formation.
KeyError: 'O'
TypeError: Unknown numpy data type: object


What's mat_L1_df?  does df implie it's pandas dataframe?  What do the cells contain.pandas often uses object dtype for strings and lists and other cell contents, which means any array derived from that will also be object dtype.  Such an array is list-like.  I'm not familiar with networkx, but am not surprised that it doesn't accept non-numeric inputs.

Pandas defines it's own non-standard integer types so they can represent missing values. When converted to NumPy arrays, they are stored with object dtype instead of int.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = pd.Series([1, 2, None], dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
x.to_numpy()
# array([1, 2, <NA>], dtype=object)


You need to ensure that mat_L1 is numeric, e.g. use mat_L1.astype(int) (or mat_L1.astype(float) depending on what you're doing).
(This is all inference based on variable names. If this is not what is happening, include a MRE in your question.)
